# Unsupported SubQuery Expression ''Fashion'': SubQuery expression refers to Outer query expressions only

Tags: mysql, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I am Using below query :

```
select UserId, Category from customer_data 
where (Category in ('Fashion','Electronics'))
and (Action in ('Click','AddToCart','Purchase'))
and customer_data.UserId not in (select ustomer_data.UserId from customer_data where customer_data.Category='Fashion' and customer_data.Category='Electronics')  ;
```

Getting below error :

```
hive> Unsupported SubQuery Expression ''Fashion'': SubQuery expression refers to Outer query expressions only.
```

I am not sure about this error , do I need to use table name for each cloumn like customer_data.Category in outer query also ?
Could you please help ?

Sample data :

```
UserId,ProductId,Category,Action
1,111,Electronics,Browse
2,112,Fashion,Click
3,113,Kids,AddtoCart
4,114,Food,Purchase
5,115,Books,Logout
6,114,Food,Click
7,113,Kids,AddtoCart
8,115,Books,Purchase
9,111,Electronics,Click
10,112,Fashion,Purchase
3,112,Fashion,Click
12,113,Kids,AddtoCart
```

desired output :

```
Output File
•   userID
•   category
```

Comment: why answer are getting deleted ?

Comment: yes exactly but my problem statement is : generate list of users who are interested in either “Fashion” category or “Electronics” category but not in both categories. User is interested if he/she has performed any of these actions (Click / AddToCart / Purchase).  so i need to satisfy this not in both category condition

Comment: One column cannot be equal to two different values for the same record. This is why this condition `customer_data.Category='Fashion' and customer_data.Category='Electronics'`makes no sense. And it seems you do not need that subquery at all. Please provide data example and desired output

Comment: sample data : UserId,ProductId,Category,Action
1,111,Electronics,Browse
2,112,Fashion,Click
3,113,Kids,AddtoCart
4,114,Food,Purchase
5,115,Books,Logout
6,114,Food,Click
7,113,Kids,AddtoCart   desired output : Output File
• userID
• category  problem statement : to generate list of users who are interested in either “Fashion” category or “Electronics” category but not in both categories. User is interested if he/she has performed any of these actions (Click / AddToCart / Purchase).

Comment: I have edited in question , could you please check ?

Comment: problem statement : To generate list of users who are interested in either “Fashion” category or “Electronics” category but not in both categories. User is interested if he/she has performed any of these actions (Click / AddToCart / Purchase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use analytic functions to calculate fashion_flag per UserId:

```
select UserId, Category
from
( --calculate User level flags
select UserId, Category,
       max(fashion_flag)     over (partition by UserId) as user_fashion_flag,
       max(electronics_flag) over (partition by UserId) as user_electronics_flag
from
(--maybe you do not need this subquery, if case will work inside max() over
    select UserId, Category,
           case when Category='Fashion'     then 1 else 0 end fashion_flag,
           case when Category='Electronics' then 1 else 0 end electronics_flag
      from customer_data 
     where (Category in ('Fashion','Electronics'))
       and (Action in ('Click','AddToCart','Purchase'))
) s

) s
where user_fashion_flag+user_electronics_flag=1 --not allow two flags at a time
;
```